# specifying line width globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=1]
\tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]
\tikzstyle reverse directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed[arrowstyle]{stealth};}}}]    

\tikzset{
        gluon/.style={decorate, draw=black,very thick, 
        decoration={coil,amplitude=4pt, segment length=5pt}} 
        }   
\makeatletter

% gluon decoration (based on the original coil decoration)

\pgfdeclaredecoration{gluon}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%>
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{-1    }{10}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-0.555}{11}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0    }{12}}
  }
  \state{last}[next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
  }
  \state{final}{}
}

\def\pgfpoint@oncoil#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@x=#1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@x=\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=#2\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@xa=0.083333333333\pgfdecorationsegmentlength%
  \advance\pgf@x by#3\pgf@xa%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5][line width=10pt]
%\draw[step=.25cm] (-2.5,-2.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
\coordinate (Origin) at (0,0);
%\fill[black] (Origin) circle (2pt);
\draw [directed] (-1.25,.5) coordinate (a_3) -- node[left] {q} (-1.25, -.5) coordinate (a_2);
\draw [reverse directed] (-1.25, -.5) coordinate (a_2) -- (-.75,0) coordinate (a_1);
\draw [reverse directed] (-.75,0) coordinate (a_1) -- (-1.25,.5) coordinate (a_3);
\draw [dashed] (-.75,0) coordinate (a_1) -- node[above] {$h_{2}(h_{1})$} (1,0) coordinate (a_5);
\draw [dashed] (1,0) coordinate (a_5) -- node[above] {$\phi_1$} (1.75,.75) coordinate (a_6);
\draw [dashed] (1,0) coordinate (a_5) -- node[below] {$\phi_1$}(1.75,-.75) coordinate (a_7);
\draw [directed] (1.75,.75) coordinate(a_6) -- (1.75,1.25) coordinate  [label = above:{$\tau^-$}] (a_8);
\draw [reverse directed] (1.75,.75) coordinate (a_6) -- (2.25,.75) coordinate [label = right:{$\tau^+$}]  (a_9);
\draw [reverse directed] (1.75,-.75) coordinate(a_10) -- (1.75,-1.25) coordinate  [label = below:{$\tau^+$}] (a_11);
\draw [directed] (1.75,-.75) coordinate(a_10) -- (2.25,-.75) coordinate  [label = right:{$\tau^-$}] (a_11);
 \node (a_12) at (-1.15,.4) {};
  \node (a_13) at (-2.2,1.4) {g};
  \path (a_12) edge[decorate,decoration={gluon, amplitude=4pt, segment length=5.25pt}] (a_13);
 \node (a_14) at (-1.15,-.4) {};
  \node (a_15) at (-2.2,-1.4) {g};
  \path (a_14) edge[decorate,decoration={gluon, amplitude=4pt, segment length=5.25pt}] (a_15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have the above Feynman diagram code. I would like to make all the lines thicker. I tried to specify the line width globally by using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5][line width=10pt]
```

but due to some reason there is no effect. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Included the coils?

Answer (score 9):

Your *error* is precisely to use two blocks of options  `[...][...]` for `tikzpicture`; this `tikzpicture` only recognizes the options of the first `[...]` and omites the second.

You must put the options separated by commas. `[scale=1.5,line width=10pt]` instead of `[scale=1.5][line width=10pt]`. (`10pt` seems too, i used `2pt`).

If you want a global definition for all pictures, you should to put *in the preamble* (or before of all pictures) something like

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=2pt}}
```

Comment: good to know that.

Comment: @user3922546: Please accept this answer then if it helps you. This will conclude this question.

Comment: I think this doesn't work for command under a `pgfonlayer` environment.